# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereBetween()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

in my case, i want to display orders completed by certain user,
with certain time range,
here is my code

```
$orders = DB::table('user_profiles')
            ->leftJoin('orders', function($join) use ($status,$order){
                $join->on('user_profiles.id','=','orders.id_user')
                    ->where('orders.status','=',$status)
                    ->whereBetween('orders.created_at',[$from,$to]);
            })
            ->selectRaw('user_profiles.*, count(orders.id_user) as order_try_count')
            ->groupBy('user_profiles.id')
            ->orderBy('order_try_count',$order)
            ->paginate(15);
```

but i get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereBetween(),
what should i do to solve this ?
thank you so much...

Comment: its in query builder https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereBetween

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an error, it's just that the JoinClause does not have a whereBetween() method.

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html

You can fix this by using a regular where clause with the operators >= and <=.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method call 'whereBetween' use 'whereIn'

```
$orders = DB::table('user_profiles')
        ->leftJoin('orders', function($join) use ($status,$order){
            $join->on('user_profiles.id','=','orders.id_user')
                ->where('orders.status','=',$status)
                ->whereIn('orders.created_at',[$from,$to]);
        })
        ->selectRaw('user_profiles.*, count(orders.id_user) as order_try_count')
        ->groupBy('user_profiles.id')
        ->orderBy('order_try_count',$order)
        ->paginate(15);
```